# How to handle connect or bind exception when using Netty

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I wrote some simple code in Netty

```
ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

And I want to handle the `java.net.ConnectException`,

> ERROR [main] (SDKUpHandler.java:37)| Unexpected exception from
>   downstream. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect:
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:12345

but I didnt find a way, for Netty version `bind` and `connect` doesnt throw them out.

From **javadoc**, connect() throws two exceptions but no`java.net.ConnectException` stuff.

> **Throws**:
>
> **ClassCastException** - if "localAddress" option's value is neither a SocketAddress nor null
>
> **ChannelPipelineException** - if this bootstrap's pipelineFactory failed to create a new ChannelPipeline

Could any body provide some solution?

Comment: Where did the error come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty is asynchronous. You need to add a ChannelFutureListener to the ChannelFuture which will get notified once the operation completes. This way you will be notified with a "success" or with the exception. Check the user documentation which contains all of this.